# Java mongoDB query probleme for any values

Tags: java, mongodb, web, request, token

I'm a French student in development
I'm actually working on a project to create a web auth
I'm trying to introduce a token system working with cookies
But the problem is my query for finding a client with his token

That's my code (don't work) to get a client with a token

```
public static DBObject findClientByToken(DB database, String token){
    DBCollection collectionUser = database.getCollection("users");
    DBObject dbObjectFilter = new BasicDBObject().append("CookieConnexion", new BasicDBObject().append("value", token).append("dateExpire",new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)));
    DBCursor cursor = collectionUser.find(dbObjectFilter);
    if (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject client = cursor.next();
        if (cursor.hasNext()){
            return null;
        } else {
            return client;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this one (work) but I have one hard value

```
public static DBObject findClientByToken(DB database, String token){
    DBCollection collectionUser = database.getCollection("users");
    DBObject dbObjectFilter = new BasicDBObject().append("CookieConnexion", new BasicDBObject().append("value", token).append("dateExpire","Wed Nov 02 17:29:54 CET 2022"));
    DBCursor cursor = collectionUser.find(dbObjectFilter);
    if (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject client = cursor.next();
        if (cursor.hasNext()){
            return null;
        } else {
            return client;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

thats a exemple of one documents [image]

Sorry for my bad english !
Hope someone can help me

Im trying to get the DBObject who match with the query

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was totally wrong my filter was just bad

the probleme come from my query thats the correct : `{"CookieConnexion.value" : "<token>"}`

that's the good code :

```
public static DBObject findClientByToken(DB database, String token){
    System.out.println("Token = " + token);
    DBCollection collectionUser = database.getCollection("users");
    DBObject dbObjectFilter = BasicDBObject.parse("{\"CookieConnexion.value\" : \"" + token + "\"}");
    System.out.println(dbObjectFilter.toString());
    DBCursor cursor = collectionUser.find(dbObjectFilter);
    if (cursor.hasNext()) {
        DBObject client = cursor.next();
        if (cursor.hasNext()){
            return null;
        } else {
            return client;
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```